# Выбор наклонения в относительном придаточном

Tags: синтаксис

В одной статье прочитала "*важным фактором использования сослагательного наклонения является наличие в главном предложении отрицания*".

Мне не понятно следующее:

> (1) Нет ни одной книги, в которой **бы** речь не **шла** о любви.
>
> (2) Нет ни одного чиновника, который **бы** не **брал** взятку.

(я правильно понимаю? во ВСЕХ книгах пишут о любви и ВСЕ чиновники берут взятку - так?)

> Нет ни одного адвоката, который **мог** **бы** выиграть это дело.

(здесь я понимаю, что ни один адвокат = НИКТО не может выиграть)

Мой вопрос: почему так? что влияет на изменение смысла? дело в наличии отрицания в обоих частях предложения в (1) и (2) и только в главной части в (3) или в семантике глагола "мочь" в примере (3) или что-то еще?

И еще:
мне сказали, что сослагательное наклонение можно поменять на изъявительное, например:

> (4) Нет ни одного фаната Мадонны, который **бы** не **знал** песню Vogue.
>
> = Нет ни одного фаната Мадонны, который не **знает** песню Vogue.

Исходя из Вашего чувства родного языка, можно заменить сослагательное наклонение на изъявительное в примерах (1), (2) и (3)?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Вид предложения**

Это СПП с придаточным определительным, подтип **качественно-типизирующий**. Это означает, что мы не столько выделяем какой-то определенный объект, сколько даем ему **качественную характеристику.** (Нам важен не конкретный предмет, а  свойство, которое этот предмет имеет или должен иметь). **Образец**: Нам нужен **такой** шкаф, который **поместился бы** в нише. Или при отрицании: Нет такого шкафа, который **поместился бы** в этой нише.

**2) Сослагательное наклонение**

Сослагательное наклонение обозначает **возможное, предполагаемое**,  а не реальное действие; если обсуждается свойство неконкретного предмета или отрицается существование такого предмета, то понятно, почему используется форма **сослагательного наклонения**.

**3) Два отрицания**

**Нет ни одного чиновника, который бы не брал взятку.** Или: нет **такого** чиновника, **который** не брал бы взятку. Два отрицания имеют значение утверждения (по образцу: **не может** не взять ― поэтому всегда берет). Поэтому и два отрицания, и наличие модального глагола "мочь" имеют утвердительное значение.

**4) Синонимия наклонений**

Нет ни одного фаната Мадонны, который **бы не знал** песню Vogue. ― Нет ни одного фаната Мадонны, который **не знает** песню Vogue.

Синонимия наклонений в русском языке существует, но чаще рассматриваются варианты замены повелительного наклонения другим наклонением. Замена сослагательного наклонения изъявительным наклонением обсуждается реже, но, **как мне кажется,** в разговорной речи это явление реально присутствует.

**Думаю**, что грамматическая точность для обозначения возможного, а не реального действия (при сослагательном наклонении) не представляется обязательной, да к тому же не фиксируется чётко на слух.

[Употребление форм одних наклонений в значении других | bibliotekar.ru](http://www.bibliotekar.ru/russkiy-yazik-2/172.htm)

Формы прошедшего времени изъявительного наклонения могут быть иногда использованы в значении, близком к значению сослагательного наклонения: "– Ах ты какой, Федя; ну, послал **(бы)** кого за водкой – и вся тут" (Мам.-Сиб.). В подобном употреблении форма прошедшего времени представляет действие не столько как предполагаемую возможность (что свойственно сослагательному наклонению...), сколько как реализованную возможность...

Comment: большое спасибо!!! особенно за комментарий два отрицания = утверждение! не знала это

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, можно говорить о синонимии наклонений в этих примерах?
а) ищу человека, который знает китайский язык.
а) ищу человека, который бы знал китайский язык.
Мне сказали, что два варианта правильные, но не могут объяснить почему имеют места оба наклонения.

Comment: Я отвечаю Вам как носитель языка, то есть в соответствии с собственным пониманием ситуации, не уточняя её по книгам. (1) Ищу человека, который знает китайский язык. Этот вариант мне кажется неточным. Создается впечатление, что есть ОДИН такой  человек и я ищу именно его. (2) Ищу человека, который бы знал китайский язык. Это более правильный вариант, так как он предполагает выбор нужного человека среди других. Мне ведь нужен не конкретный человек, а ЛЮБОЙ, кто знает язык.

Comment: Многие люди знают китайский язык, поэтому у меня есть ПОТЕНЦИАЛЬНАЯ возможность найти такого человека. Именно потенциальную ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ обозначает здесь сослагательное наклонение.  (А вообще говоря,  любые вопросы удобнее задавать на форуме. Сейчас Вы услышали только мое частное мнение, а там можно получить ответы разных  участников).

Comment: большое спасибо! сейчас задам на форуме тогда (но боюсь надоела всем с сослагательным наклонением jajajajaja =)

Comment: Конечно, задайте. Чем больше вопросов, тем  престижнее форум. Носители языка часто используют грамматику интуитивно,  особо не задумываясь, а так у них появится возможность "размять мозги". Тем более что эту информацию в книгах не найдешь, придется самим подумать.