# Наклонение в относительном предложении

Tags: синтаксис, наклонение

Слышала о понятии "синонимия наклонений", но не знаю, можно ли применять этот термин к моему вопросу.
На Google есть пример из объявления:

> Хочу встретить мужчину, который не **боится** принимать решения.

Она его еще не встретила, почему индикатив? В моем языке сослагательное наклонение стояло бы в придаточном предложении, потому что референт пока еще гипотетический и еще не найден. Плюс не известно, существует такой или нет.

Носитель языка сказал, что такая опция возможна тоже (но не может объяснить почему):

> Хочу встретить мужчину, который **бы** не **боялся** принимать решения.

Для вашего уха они звучат одинаково на самом деле или вы делаете семантическое различие?

[Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428301) в комментарии я задавала вопрос с примерами:

> а) ищу человека, который **знает** китайский язык;
>
> б) ищу человека, который **бы** **знал** китайский язык.

Получается, в этих примерах есть семантическая разница и они различаются от примеров о мужчине?

Comment: Конечный смысл одинаковый у этих фраз. Вторую чаще скажут в порядке ***не боялся бы**,* но и так тоже можно. Может, поменять ***такая опция возможна*** на ***такой вариант возможен**?*

Comment: Кстати, в английском так же, как и в русском, в этом примере будет. А во французском, наверно, как в Вашем испанском, да?

Comment: "_референт пока еще гипотетический и еще не найден_" - он ещё не найден, но принимать решения-то он уже не боится, верно? :-) Вы правильно заметили, что формально правильней был бы второй вариант, но как ни странно, первый вариант чаще используется в разговорной речи, да пожалуй, и звучит лучше. У второго, "правильного", варианта есть такой неуловимый формальный оттенок. Слишком правильный он, что ли. Обосновать не могу, это чисто личное мнение.

Comment: Артём, не совсем поняла, что вы имеете в виду "в английском"? "...who would..."?
да, в испанском мы не будем использовать индикатив в таком контексте, unless я уже знаю/уже встречала такого мужчину, который не боится принимать решения и просто хожу по улицам и надеюсь снова встретить этого человека =)

Comment: По-английски так же, как по-русски в данном случае. ‘I want to meet a man who ***doesn't care*** a lot of making important decisions’.

Comment: 1) "_Получается, в этих примерах есть семантическая разница и они различаются от примеров о мужчине?_" - если разница и есть, без микроскопа её не увидеть. 2) "_ищу человека, который знает китайский язык_" - там в комментариях правильно сказали, что можно было бы подумать, что речь идёт о единственном человеке. Но в реальной жизни люди говорят именно так, и никаких неясностей не возникает. В обоих ваших примерах оба варианта равнозначны, при этом первый вариант более употребителен в разговоре, хоть и менее правилен.

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу смысловое различие. В первом случае речь идёт о человеке, систематически проявляющем желаемое качество, и наряду с надеждой на встречу выражается уверенность в существовании таких мужчин. В альтернативном примере выражается надежда, что встреченный мужчина (благодаря качествам, которые не обязательно уже проявлялись) в будущих сложных ситуациях, которые **могут** возникнуть (от этого сослагательность), *поведёт* себя должным образом.

Во второй паре примеров первое предложение воспринимается естественно: такой человек где-то уже есть (знание китайского - не фантастическое явление) и его хотят встретить. Второе предложение менее убедительно, поскольку новых смыслов не содержит и не может истолковываться в духе расмотренного выше предложения о "небоязни", разве что освоить язык он должен был бы к моменту гипотетической "встречи". Но такое допущение не вполне естественно, поскольку освоение китайского - дело долгое: китаисты шутят, что "его трудно изучать только первые 10 лет". Так что "знайка" нужен "готовеньким". Более логичным выглядело бы аналогичное предложение с сослагательностью в первой части: "*Хотела бы встретить такого, что знал бы китайский* [но такое маловероятно]". Здесь отличие состоит в меньшем оптимизме говорящей.

Answer (score 1):

**С учетом ответа Alex_ander,** который мне кажется очень разумным (голосую за него), я бы сейчас ответила так.

1) ***Хочу встретить мужчину, который не боится принимать решения.***

Почему индикатив? Такой мужчина, конечно же,  существует, как и существует желание его встретить. Нет причин для сослагательного наклонения.

Это важное требование: ведь в жизни **постоянно** возникают ситуации, когда это качество необходимо.

***Хочу встретить мужчину, который не боялся бы принимать решения.***

**Смягченный вариант**:  жизнь – это не одни сплошные проблемы, которые надо постоянно решать. Но **если** такая необходимость возникнет, то надо уметь принимать решение (сослагательное наклонение подразумевает это условие).

2)  ***Ищу человека, который знает китайский язык.***

Он постоянно будет заниматься переводами, это будет его основной обязанностью.

***Ищу человека, который знал бы китайский язык.***

Этот вариант более уместен для такого объявления:  ***Ищу секретаря, который знал бы китайский язык.***

Это будет его дополнительная обязанность. Переводами он будет заниматься, **если** в этом будет необходимость (сослагательное значение).